# Open URL in mobile browser from mobile application

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

I am using JavaScript to open a URL in a mobile browser from a mobile application (not in app view).

Using the code given below - it opens in app view instead of new mobile browser.

```
function test() {
    window.open("https://www.google.com/" , '_system')
}
```

Alternately, the tag given below works but I want to avoid it.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target='_system'>...</a>
```

Comment: You can intercept every link clicked with shouldInterceptRequest() belonging to the WebView class, from there you create an intent that starts the browser

Answer (score 0):

"https://www.google.com/" start with http or https, if you want to jump URL in mobile browser to mobile application, you should use a private protocol，such as "intent://youku.xxxx.com/23/2346". good luck!

Comment: Its "https://www.google.com/" , my requirement is from mobile application to mobile browser but not the other way around.

Comment: Uri  uri = Uri.parse(“http://www.xxxxx.com”);
Intent  intent = new  Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: please try this in your mobile app, it will start a browser app.